# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio : Select, Export, Append

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to take information from two linked tables, linked by pkfield. The basic layout of what I need to do is:

From table A:

```
 Name, Year Active where active is true
 ID is the PK
```

From Table B:

```
 ID and Type where Table A.Active is true
 ID is the link back to Table A (obviously)
```

I want to export all of that to a .CSV file, change the year, and then APPEND it back to the respective tables as new records.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Maybe in two separate queries? I believe the ID field in Table A is automatically generated.

Comment: Hello and thanks for replying. In further checking my table structure, I have found the following: Table A Columns: MagID(PK), MagCode, Year, Name, Parcel, Active. Table B Columns: TypeID (PK), MagID(FK from Table A), TypeCode, and LastID. Normally, data is entered into Table B via a form with MagCode (Table A), TypeCode, Year (Table A), and LastID. So, each MagID/Year combination has two entries for TypeCode and LastID. Example: MagID Fred, TypeCode XR, Year 2018, LastID 2008; MagID Fred, TypeCode LR, Year 2018, LastID 492. Will that automatically link correctly when appended?

Answer (score 0):

Query to export data into csv:

```
select Name,Year,Active,Type
From tableA A JOIN tableB B on A.ID=B.ID
Where A.Active=1
```

You can write below query against each row in CSV after changing the Year.

```
insert into tableA(Name,Year,Active) values(csvcol_Name,csvcol_Year,1)
insert into tableB(ID,Type) values(@@Identity,csvcol_Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found I can use the import/export wizard. I just needed to use the 64-bit one since it's on a 64-bit machine. Also, information can be modified as needed and pasted into the table. No need for code...so far.

Update: Turns out this is only partially true. I can get the correct information into table B without any trouble...but how do I establish the correct links back to table A without having to manually enter the information into the form that apparently establishes those links. There are about 550 records to be entered...twice. Out of necessity, it's not a centralized database. Switches are turned off on one computer and on on the other. They can't be combined. So...how do I avoid...or DO I avoid...having to enter 1100 records between two machines? Can I establish the links from within SQL Management Studio?